# Can I give my facebook messenger chat bot the exclusivity of answering users?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I connected a Facebook messenger bot to a page with several admins. I am not yet very familiar with the facebook messenger platform but it looks like when a user messages our page. Admins see the incoming message and can respond to it. Can I deactivate this ? I want my bot and only my bot to handle incoming message, I don't want admins of the page to be able to interfere in the user experience. I was thinking it should be easy to do but I cannot find how to do that. To recap : I would like my chat bot to have the exclusivity of chatting with users from my facebook page, do you know how to do this ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I was unable to find anyway to make the conversation between a Facebook messenger bot and a Facebook user private (in the sense that no page admin, editor or moderator would be able to see the conversation from the page inbox). If you want your bot to have a private conversation with your users for certain sensitive actions, your only option as of now seems to be using a [webview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview).

Using a Webview can complicate a little bit your workflow because Webviews are not supported the same way on all platforms but at least, it will enable you to gather direct inputs from your users that your Facebook page moderators will not be able to see from the admin page.

Answer (score 2):

> Admins see the incoming message and can respond to it. Can I deactivate this ?

No, you can not.

Bots are meant to be able to *help* with page tasks regarding answering user messages, but not to take over control completely.

Comment: Ok. Then it means that the only option to prevent admins (and other roles) to see sensitive information that could be entered by users is to use a webview. I still think that this is a mistake from Facebook not to allow private chat conversations between the bot and the user. I think most Facebook users do not realize their conversation with a bot is not at all private and it is Wrong(tm). My 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to this [Facebook help article](https://www.facebook.com/help/323502271070625/), the roles available to your page admins are listed there. Use it as your guide.